# create a responsive grid with header and footer

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I have a grid placed inside a header and footer. This grid is viewed normally in small screens.

```
<ion-header>
       <img src="assets/img/main-logo.png" alt=""/>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="has-header" >
             <ion-grid style="padding:0;" >
               <ion-row style="padding:0;">
                  <ion-col>
                     <img src="img.png">
                  </ion-col>
                   <ion-col>
                     <img src="img.png">
                  </ion-col>
                   <ion-col>
                     <img src="img.png">
                  </ion-col>
                   <ion-col>
                     <img src="img.png">
                  </ion-col>
               </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
  </ion-content>

 <ion-footer>
          footer Bar will be here
 </ion-footer>
```

I have 4 rows & col or more. When viewing this grid in small mobile its visible within the screen, but viewing the same on a tab gives blank screen at the bottom.

**I want the header content footer to be visible in all screen sizes without scrolling.**

Comment: Did you try looking at sticky footer.? It helps you place the footer in the bottom of the screen even if the content is less. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding a `ion-footer` inside your `ion-content`, everything inside it will scroll with the view, thus in big screens that the grid will appear smaller the footer will go up.

Try this

```
<ion-content class="has-header" >
  <ion-grid no-padding> <!-- TRY NOT TO USE INLINE CSS, IT'S BAD. IN THIS CASE USE IONIC no-padding CSS UTILITY -->
    <ion-row no-padding>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="img.png">
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="img.png">
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="img.png">
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="img.png">
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <!-- footer Bar will be here -->
</ion-footer>
```

This way the footer'll always be on the bottom of your page regardless your viewport.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what i need is that the grid should expand from header to footer covering the space in whatever the screen size is